# iphone Core Data - Why Core data is so slow?

Tags: iphone, core-data

My table in the CoreData has like 8 columns, all are strings. The largest string's length is less than 10K.

First, I use the following codes to retrieve the rows:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(URL ==[c] %@)", url]];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Time" ascending:NO selector:nil];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:descriptors];
[sortDescriptor release];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Here is the performance log:

> 2011-05-10 11:47:18.743 Test2[2176:5907] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 2.6172s
>
> 2011-05-10 11:47:21.600 Test2[2176:5907] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 2.8577s for 144 rows.

**144 rows for more than 2 secs?**

Then I construct an non-coredata object for each row:

```
if ([array count] > 0) {
    for (Item *item in array) {
        SimpleItem *sitem = [[SimpleItem alloc] init];
        sitem.Title = item.Title;
        sitem.Summary = item.Summary;
        sitem.URL = item.URL;
        [dataDict setObject:sitem forKey:item.URL];
        [sitem release];
    }
    [dataDict release];
}
```

part of The performance log ( i think for one row read) for the above codes is:

> 2011-05-10 11:47:21.617 Test2[2176:5907] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZURL, t0.ZSUMMARY, , t0.ZIMAGEURL, t0.ZTITLE, t0.ZURL, t0.ZTIME FROM ZITEM t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ?
>
> 2011-05-10 11:47:21.629 Test2[2176:5907] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0098s
>
> 2011-05-10 11:47:21.633 Test2[2176:5907] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0162s for 1 rows.

It seems faults are there.

Anyone can help me to improve the performance?

Also, I have checked "Index" option for URL when I edit the data model in xcode. Is that enough for setting up an index?

Comment: More details are needed to provided any useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't used any indexes on your columns, that might help speed things up a little but if you're searching strings 10K in length, CoreData probably isn't the way to go.

And CoreData isn't a database - it deals with some things less efficiently that just using sqlite. In CoreData, objects are completely loaded into memory for some operations - loading 10K * 144 records into memory probably won't be the fastest thing in the world :)

Try writing your database code in sqlite and see if it's any faster.

Comment: Hi there. I think in my case, CoreData hasn't loaded 144 rows content into memory at once. Instead, only when I read each property of one row, shall the content be loaded into memory. I update my question with complete log. by the way, how to setup index? thanks

Comment: If you choose an attribute (in this case, URL) there should be a tickbox marked 'Indexed' in your property inspector view in XCode.

Comment: You could also take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html - an NSFetchedResultsController will get results in batches instead of getting all of them at once.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, I have indexed. Could you please have a look at my question again, I updated more details. I think CoreData will use faults when it retrieves rows into an array, only if I read each NSManagedObject in that array, shall the content be fullfiled. Am I right?

Comment: That should be the case, yes. What output do you get if you put `NSLog(@"%@", item);` as the first line in your loop - that should tell you if the `item`'s data is a fault or if it's been loaded already.

Comment: Thanks. I tried. Most of the log are <Item: 0x4e4a940> (entity: Item; id: 0x4e54fd0 <x-coredata://88A5F536-B21C-45D4-AEAF-9EE1607C03DE/Item/p154> ; data: <fault>)

Comment: in that case you're right, the items aren't being loaded on the first query. Is there any way you can do the query without the `[c]` - that's going to make things slower :)

Comment: I wish I knew. What I want to retrieve is "all items whose URL equals to *url*". I removed [c] (no problem for my case), yes, it boosts to "CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.6524s for 144 rows." Thanks deanWombourne, any other suggestions?? Anyway, your answer and help are correct one.

Comment: The only thing you can do now is change the UI to show a 'please wait' message; I think that might be as fast as you're going to get it. String matching is notoriously slow.